# How to do basic plotting of a multivariate function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have to compute the limit of the function

`(c^(2n) - 1)/(c^(2n) + 1) as n = 1,2,3` ... goes to infinity

The behavior of the function will depend on the parameter c, and I would like to illustrate is by plotting the first 100 (or so) values of the sequence for different values of c - say three plots, one for `c = 1`, one for `-1 < c < 1` and one for `c > 1`, if possible all within one "picture".

What is the best way to approach this in MATLAB?

Comment: It depends on how much you already know about the MATLAB syntax. If you can code that expression in MATLAB and know the syntax for a simple `for` loop, I think you can come up with a more specific question. If not, I think you should probably talk to your Prof/TA to get started on MATLAB basics.

Comment: The best way is to TRY something. You learn by doing, not by someone else giving you the answer. And if you have absolutely no idea about what to do, then you have not bothered to get through the real basics of MATLAB. So what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an inline function, hold all and legend. Here is a simple example

```
n=1:100;
f = @(c) (c.^(2.*n) - 1)./(c.^(2.*n) + 1); 
hold all;
plot(n,f(0.7),'.-');
plot(n,f(0.9),'.-');
plot(n,f(0.95),'.-');
plot(n,f(1),'.-');
plot(n,f(1.05),'.-');
plot(n,f(1.3),'.-');
plot(n,f(1.1),'.-');
legend('c=0.7','c=0.9','c=0.95','c=1.0','c=1.05','c=1.3','c=1.1');
```

The output of this looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like:

```
% Clean up, this isn't necessary if you're throwing this in a function
%   and not a script.
close all
clear all
clc

% Define your function
f = @(c,n)( (c^(2*n) - 1)/(c^(2*n) + 1) );

% An array containing the values of c you want to use
C = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2];

% N will contain 500 points, equally spaced between 1 and 20.
%   (Modify these arguments as necessary)
N = linspace(1,20,500);

% Initialize an output matrix
Y = zeros(length(N), length(C));
for i = [1:length(C)]
    c = C(i);

    for j = [1:length(N)]
        n = N(j);

        % Compute value of function
        y = f(c,n);

        % Store it
        Y(j,i) = y;
    end%for
end%for

% Plot it
plot(N,Y);

% Generate Legend
lt = cell(1,length(C));
for i = [1:length(C)]
    lt{i} = sprintf('C = %s', num2str(C(i)));
end%for
legend(lt);
```

You could optimize it by modifying the function `f` to accept and return vectors, but this explicit version probably shows what is going on better.